# Domain of definition of standard Friedmann equation

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

The standard Friedmann equation is defined as

$$H(z)=H_{0}\sqrt{\Omega_{m}(1+z)^3+\Omega_{r}(1+z)^4+\Omega_{\Lambda}}$$
So, this equation is only defined in $z>0$?

If this is the case what how do I know what will happen in the "future"?

As far as I understand that $z=0$ is the actual state of the universe and $z>0$ is "the past".

**Edit: My confusion**

The Friedmann equation is something that I don't understand really well, so sorry if this is a basic confusion. Take the equation for $\rho_{m}=\rho_{m_{0}}(1+z)^3$, we can  deduce $\rho_{m_{0}}$ using the critial density, and "my problem" is that for $z<1$ , for example $z=-2$ you get that $\rho_{m}$ is negative, for my this is non sence.

Comment: Why would it only be defined for $z>0$?

Comment: Is something that I don't understand well, so I ask in this place looking for clarification. Take the equation for $\rho_{m}=\rho_{m_{0}}(1+z)^3$, we can  deduce $\rho_{m_{0}}$ using the critial density, and "my problem" is that for $z<1$ , for example $z=-2$ you get that $\rho_{m}$ is negative, for my this is non sence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say that this is the *definition* of the Friedmann equation, although it is a way of writing it.

It is clearly well defined for $1 + z > 0$, i.e. $z>-1$. Indeed redshift does not make sense for $z \leq -1$, so I don't see where the problem lies.

Comment: As I say before is a personal confusion. Since we are now $z=0$ how do I know what will happend in the "future" with the Friedmann equation?

Comment: Oh, you  are right this is not the definition of the Friedmann equation. This is a particular way of writing the Friedmann equation in some specific model.

Comment: The future is values $-1<z<0$.

Comment: I think that your answer has physical sense, since in the standard model the future would be $\Lambda$ dominated.

Comment: Yes, that is right for standard cosmology with accelerating expansion (of course, if the universe were to start to contract, $z$ would increase and ultimately you would have $z>0 again).